# Should I make backups when deploy AMP?

Tags: backup, alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-maven

I want to make a little customization of the Share tier.

For this purpose I have prepared the relevant AMP file in which override some current properties. I know how to do it in another way, but I interested in that way.

Should I make any backups before deploying AMP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Backups of what?
Your WAR file will be backed up, unless you specify a -nobackup command.

http://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/tasks/dev-extensions-tutorials-simple-module-install-amp.html

Answer (score 1):

Although the question has already been answered, I would like to give my opinion, based on AMP development and deploying experience.

You have to do data/document backup on a regular basis, but you must do backup before installing AMP.

Some nodes properties can be added/removed/modified more than once especially during early AMP development stage. This can likely lead to Alfresco not starting up or some node being gone or unusable forever. I remember a plugin tutorial from Jeff Pott, mentioning a conservative (start with few properties, add later if needed rather than removing) approach when developing AMP, because a simple removed property could cause huge problems.

So...a backup before installing AMP is strongly recommended.